# What are the prerequisites to make an REST API call hosted on Azure from On-Premise?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-rest-api

I am new to Azure and would need some help in understanding the prerequisites for making an REST API call hosted on Azure.

1. Do we need security/firewall/gateway changes for making an API call?
2. how to authenticate the requests?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about calling your API hosted on Azure from your local network, you don't need any change. There are multiple ways to authenticate the requests, you can use your own Identity Provider (Identity Server) or use Azure AD to authenticate the requests.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

So the first step would be get a token from Azure AD, then pass it as a Authorization header in your request payload to the API. It will validate the token against Azure AD, and in case it's valid, will process the request and generate the response.

For the opposite, azure service calling on premises services, you need to setup a VPN:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/connect-an-on-premises-network-to-a-microsoft-azure-virtual-network

Comment: Thank you for the links!